# Generating traffic with DF flag set

Tags: traffic

is there a tool which I could generate TCP traffic with the Don't Fragment flag set?
I used iperf, but I cannot find an option for DF.

Comment: Unfortunately, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic on SE sites, except [softwarerecs.se] and [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux command nping has a `--df` flag for setting the Don't Fragment bit in the flags; it also can generate TCP and UDP traffic, not just ICMP.  Will that help?

Comment: On Windows it's `ping -f` followed by any other flags and the destination hostname or IP address.

Comment: @ToddWilcox ... I have very little recent experience with Windows: can Windows ping generate TCP traffic?

Comment: Oh, no I don't believe so. I was focused on the not fragmenting.